Pro Tanto Duties Meaning
I'm reading articles on the justification of moral duties to compensate.
Many articles, including by V Tadros and S Steel, refer to pro tanto duties or wrongs.
For instance, Tadros says: "Hiker's conduct seems permissible all things considered, but pro tanto wrong."
And Steel says: "the article is primarily concerned with compensatory duties that arise from all-things-considered wrongs or pro tanto wrongs"
Am I correct to assume that pro tanto duties are duties imposed on us to do something just because there is a solid reason to do so, but if we consider the context and competing claims, we may not have that duty all things considered?

Pro tanto literally translates as "to its extent" and is the antonym of "all things considered", similar expressions are "on its own", "as such", "in abstracto" or "ceteris paribus". Ross originally called pro tanto duties "prima facie duties" (on their face) and explained that they are not duties, but rather partial moral considerations that contribute to the duties' determination, see Dabbagh. For example, telling the truth, taken pro tanto, would impose a duty, but in context it is only one moral factor among others that determine it.
